# Check if the activity active

Tags: android

When an incoming call or the application is minimized - triggers run(). This should not be

```
final View activityRootView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        activityRootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            private int lastHeight;
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                if (lastHeight == 0) {
                    lastHeight = activityRootView.getHeight();
                }
  if (lastHeight < activityRootView.getHeight() && activityRootView.getHeight() - lastHeight > 100 && **current activity active**) {
                    WebView vw = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
                    vw.loadUrl("javascript:run()");
                }
                lastHeight = activityRootView.getHeight(); 
            }
        });
```

Comment: I don't understand...what's your question and what's wrong in your code?

Comment: run() is triggered when hiding the keyboard. If I force hide the keyboard - this is normal. But if I get an incoming call - the keypad itself is hiding and triggered run () is not normal. I think need to put a condition if (lastHeight < activityRootView.getHeight() && activityRootView.getHeight() - lastHeight > 100 && **condition here: If the activity is active**) to avoid triggering the run() when  incoming call. I don't know how should look the condition